# How to delete Exchange 2010 mailbox from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, exchange-server

I need to be able to delete an Exchange 2010 mailbox from a batch file.
I do not want to use a script file in this case.

For example:

@powershell -command "Remove-Mailbox -Identity Domain1\John.Doe -Permanent $true"

The above command fails with error "The term 'Remove-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the batch file directly on an Exchange server or from a remote server? That greatly changes how you are able to connect to Exchange via PowerShell, and instantiate the Exchange cmdlets.

Take a look at this similar question, in which the poster answered his own question by calling RemoteExchange.ps1, directly on the Exchange server itself.

[How to use Exchange 2010 cmdlet in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265604/how-to-use-exchange-2010-cmdlet-in-batch-file?rq=1)

If that doesn't help you, or you need to execute Exchange cmdlets from a remote machine that does not have any exchange components installed, I have some scripts I can provide tomorrow.

Comment: For executing a single command, it's much quicker and simpler to create a session to the Powershell session on an Exchange server, and then use Invoke-Command and direct the command to that session.